# After updating flutter version not able to run the application

Tags: flutter

I have upgraded the flutter version;

**From**

```
Flutter 3.3.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4f9d92fbbd (10 months ago) • 2022-09-06 17:54:53 -0700
Engine • revision 3efdf03e73
Tools • Dart 2.18.0 • DevTools 2.15.0
```

**To**

```
Flutter 3.10.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 796c8ef792 (5 weeks ago) • 2023-06-13 15:51:02 -0700
Engine • revision 45f6e00911
Tools • Dart 3.0.5 • DevTools 2.23.1
```

I have upgraded the pubspec according to the latest version, but when I am trying to build the application, it's throwing an error with the following;

```
 * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No signature of method: build_58ywicibeljyvd9hmz1hf35px.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_58ywicibeljyvd9hmz1hf35px$_run_closure2) values: [build_58ywicibeljyvd9hmz1hf35px$_run_closure2@51a7d2a1]
```

Added the flutter inappwebview the following way;

```
flutter_inappwebview:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/rshrc/flutter_inappwebview
      ref: master
```

Since I am trying to add it normally, I am encountering conflicts with the versions, as shown below;

```
 Because cred_components >=0.0.7 depends on hello_sign_plugin ^0.0.3 and no versions of hello_sign_plugin match >0.0.3 <0.1.0, cred_components >=0.0.7 requires hello_sign_plugin 0.0.3.
And because hello_sign_plugin 0.0.3 depends on flutter_inappwebview ^6.0.0-beta.22, cred_components >=0.0.7 requires flutter_inappwebview ^6.0.0-beta.22.
And because youtube_player_flutter 8.1.2 depends on flutter_inappwebview ^5.7.2+3 and no versions of youtube_player_flutter match >8.1.2 <9.0.0, cred_components >=0.0.7 is incompatible with youtube_player_flutter ^8.1.2.
So, because dsaas depends on both youtube_player_flutter ^8.1.2 and cred_components ^0.0.7, version solving failed.
```

How to resolve this conflicts?

Comment: instead of changing manually , try `flutter pub upgrade`. it will show the major version can be changed, if the issue persist, try `any` on version number and after pub get, check pubspec.lock file what was the cause.

Comment: remove the following line from your build.gradle file in the app level- useProguard = true

Comment: useProguard commenting didn't work. I tried before also

Answer (score 0):

try running  `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`  in your project directory,
this cmd will handle packages versioning.